# How can i restore an Kinetic.js mouseevent

Tags: javascript, canvas, mouseevent, restore, kineticjs

How can i restore an Kinetic.js event?
I programmed an Kinetic.js "shape-button", it listen to mouseover and mouseout events. when i click on it it changes the color and don't listen to mouseover/out anymore. I want it to listen to mouseover and mouseout again when i click it a second time. I tryed to remove one click event and restore the other in both events, but i cant restore one event with
`circle.on("eventname")` 
i have to define a function like 
`circle.on("eventname", function(){//do stuff here});`
but thad would end in an continous loop of define functions

Thank you for answering!

here is my code:

```
<head>
        <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.0.0.js">    </script>
        <script>

            var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
            var sfcolor = '#00ff00'         
            var nfcolor = '#0000ff'         
            var cfcolor = '#ff0000'         
            var smcolor = '#009a00'         
            var nmcolor = '#00009a'         
            var cmcolor = '#9a0000'         
            var slcolor = '#007000'         
            var nlcolor = '#000070'         
            var clcolor = '#700000'         
            function drawCircle(sx, sy, sradius, sstrokeWidth) {
                var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({ container: "container", width: 578, height: 200 });
                var circleLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
                //circle
                var scircle = new Kinetic.Circle({
                    x: sx,
                    y: sy,
                    radius: sradius,
                    fill:  {
                    start: {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                        radius: 0
                    },
                    end: {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                    radius: sradius
                    },
                colorStops: [0, sfcolor, 0.5, smcolor, 1, slcolor]
      },
                    stroke: slcolor,
                    strokeWidth: sstrokeWidth
                });
                scircle.on("mouseover.event1", function() {
                    this.setFill({
                        start: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: 0
                        },
                        end: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: sradius
                        },
                        colorStops: [0, nfcolor, 0.5, nmcolor, 1, nlcolor]
                });
                    this.setStroke(nlcolor);
                    scircle.off("click.event2");
                    circleLayer.draw();
                });
                scircle.on("mouseout.event1", function() {
                    this.setFill({
                        start: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: 0
                        },
                        end: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: sradius
                        },
                        colorStops: [0, sfcolor, 0.5, smcolor, 1, slcolor]
                    });
                    this.setStroke(slcolor);
                    scircle.off("click.event2");
                    circleLayer.draw();
                });
                scircle.on("click.event1", function() {
                    this.setFill({
                        start: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: 0
                        },
                        end: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: sradius
                        },
                        colorStops: [0, cfcolor, 0.5, cmcolor, 1, clcolor]
                    });
                    this.setStroke(clcolor);
                    scircle.off("mouseout.event1");
                    scircle.off("mouseover.event1");
                    scircle.off("click.event1");
                    scircle.on("click.event2", function() {
                        this.setFill({
                            start: {
                                x: 0,
                                y: 0,
                                radius: 0
                            },
                            end: {
                                x: 0,
                                y: 0,
                                radius: sradius
                            },
                            colorStops: [0, nfcolor, 0.5, nmcolor, 1, nlcolor]
                        });
                        this.setStroke(clcolor);
                        scircle.on("mouseout.event1");
                        scircle.on("mouseover.event1");
                        scircle.on("click.event1");
                        scircle.off("click.event2");
                        circleLayer.draw();
                    });

                    circleLayer.draw();
                });


                circleLayer.add(scircle);
                stage.add(circleLayer);
            }
            window.onload = function() {
                drawCircle(200, 100, 50, 3);
            };
        </script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"On" function require two parameters. The first one is the event name. The second one is the handler. 
You need to pass the handler to correctly restore the event.

I think you should try assign your events to handlers and pass them to scircle.on

See if the code below works

Cheers!

```
<head>
        <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.0.0.js">    </script>
        <script>

            var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
            var sfcolor = '#00ff00'         
            var nfcolor = '#0000ff'         
            var cfcolor = '#ff0000'         
            var smcolor = '#009a00'         
            var nmcolor = '#00009a'         
            var cmcolor = '#9a0000'         
            var slcolor = '#007000'         
            var nlcolor = '#000070'         
            var clcolor = '#700000'         
            function drawCircle(sx, sy, sradius, sstrokeWidth) {
                var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({ container: "container", width: 578, height: 200 });
                var circleLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
                //circle
                var scircle = new Kinetic.Circle({
                    x: sx,
                    y: sy,
                    radius: sradius,
                    fill:  {
                    start: {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                        radius: 0
                    },
                    end: {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                        radius: sradius
                    },
                    colorStops: [0, sfcolor, 0.5, smcolor, 1, slcolor]
                    },
                    stroke: slcolor,
                    strokeWidth: sstrokeWidth
                });

                mouseover_event1 = function() {
                    this.setFill({
                        start: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: 0
                        },
                        end: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: sradius
                        },
                        colorStops: [0, nfcolor, 0.5, nmcolor, 1, nlcolor]
                    });
                    this.setStroke(nlcolor);
                    scircle.off("click.event2");
                    circleLayer.draw();
                };
                scircle.on("mouseover.event1", mouseover_event1);

                mouseout_event1 = function() {
                    this.setFill({
                        start: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: 0
                        },
                        end: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: sradius
                        },
                        colorStops: [0, sfcolor, 0.5, smcolor, 1, slcolor]
                    });
                    this.setStroke(slcolor);
                    scircle.off("click.event2");
                    circleLayer.draw();
                }
                scircle.on("mouseout.event1", mouseout_event1);

                click_event1 = function() {
                    this.setFill({
                        start: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: 0
                        },
                        end: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: sradius
                        },
                        colorStops: [0, cfcolor, 0.5, cmcolor, 1, clcolor]
                    });
                    this.setStroke(clcolor);
                    scircle.off("mouseout.event1");
                    scircle.off("mouseover.event1");
                    scircle.off("click.event1");
                    scircle.on("click.event2", click_event2);

                    circleLayer.draw();
                };

                click_event2 = function() {
                    this.setFill({
                        start: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: 0
                        },
                        end: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: sradius
                        },
                        colorStops: [0, nfcolor, 0.5, nmcolor, 1, nlcolor]
                    });
                    this.setStroke(clcolor);
                    scircle.on("mouseout.event1", mouseout_event1);
                    scircle.on("mouseover.event1", mouseover_event1);
                    scircle.on("click.event1", click_event1);
                    scircle.off("click.event2");
                    circleLayer.draw();
                };

                scircle.on("click.event1", click_event1);


                circleLayer.add(scircle);
                stage.add(circleLayer);
            }
            window.onload = function() {
                drawCircle(200, 100, 50, 3);
            };
        </script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Hey maiconio, its super efective! Thank you for Helping me. Do you have an idea how i can genarate some functions like thad? i have to count the event id up(test.event1 to test.event3 and tes.event2 to test.event4) and i have to cound the container id up and the functionid. Would be nice if you answer, Greets Ben Green